# User is not getting authenticated via Login Control ASP .NET

Tags: c#, amazon-ec2, asp.net-membership, amazon-elb, f5

**Infra Details:**

We have a enterprise level .net application deployed on the AWS EC2 instances behind the load balancers (AWS ELB) and all the traffic is routed via F5 and AWS Route53.

**Issue:**

The issue I am facing is whenever a user with valid credentials tries to login into my application the user is getting error message - "User could not be authenticated" and somehow the username is getting replaced with unknown string 'hsilver'. this issue goes away if user clears his cookies / cache

I am more curious to know how can the username be replaced with unknown string (we do not have any code for setting the username in login control on login page.)

I could see some logs at IIS level which says - "Event code: 4005 Event message: Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied has expired."

Still not able to relate from where the request is being returned to the browser and how the username getting replaced by unknown string 'hsilver'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could identify the root cause, one of our server's time in production pool was out of sync somehow, so ASP.NET was not able to decrypt the authentication ticket received from client.